# How can I add autocomplete to an Excel drop down validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, autocomplete, validation

I have an excel column where a drop down validation is performed on a list on a separate sheet. I would like to allow the user to start typing in the cell and have the names on the reference list begin to fill in cell.
For example, on the list I am validating against there may be a Smith, John, Scythe, Jane, and Mary, Typhoid. Instead of tapping the drop down, I want to be able to type "S", have both of the "S" last names appear in the drop down, type "m" and have Smith, John be the only option left. If invalid data is entered, nothing should save (or some other default behavior similar to validation should occur). I am trying to avoid using the drop down selectors because the users are on tablets and find the drop down cumbersome

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**How it works:**

- From **Developer Tab** click **Design Mode**, 
  left to it is **Insert** then from **ActiceX 
  Controls** section, Select **Combo Box** and 
  draw anywhere in blank area of you Sheet.
- Select the **ComboBox** and *Right Click* to 
  get the **Properties** dialogue.
- Scroll down to select, **1-fmMatchEntryComplete 
  in the MatchEntry** Field
- Then reach to **Linked Cell** and Fill **Cell 
  address** where you want to fill data, in shown 
  example is `C116`.
- Next is fill Source Data Range in **List Fill 
  Range**, here is `$A$116:$A$140`.
- **Save** the Sheet.

[image]

- Now, Click Drop Down List (Combo Box), then 
  type the first letter into the box, the 
  corresponding word will be completed 
  automatically.

See the First Screen Shot above.

*Adjust Cell references for Source Data in `A116:A140` as needed.*

Comment: That's the closest thing I have ever seen to get this functionality, thanks for the answer! However, does that mean we need to create a combo box like this for _each_ cell of the column? That seems unapplicable for a list that could grow.

Comment: Glad to help you @Pacopaco ,,, yes ,, if U are looking for  AUTO Complete then need as many Combo Boxes,, if U have Multiple Column for the same peroration,,,, this is the ultimate non programming method,,, is tedious but quit useful too.  And if you are expecting the LIST to add on values in future or the SOURCE list A116:A140 will grow then the DYANAMIC NAMED RANGE can be used instead of A116:A140☺

Comment: ah, nice, the dynamic range will definitely help!